# ObservableCollection Not updating GUI

Tags: wpf, mvvm, observablecollection

I am trying to update the my UI using observable collection but that i not happening in my case,even i have tried to update it using "marshall the data onto the Gui thread",that is even not working for me.Here i am updatig my code please let me know where i am wrong.
**XAML**

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding BindFiles, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectionMode="Single"     CanUserSortColumns="False"  x:Name="dataGrid1"    BorderBrush="Transparent" Canvas.Left="1" Canvas.Top="50" Background="{Binding ElementName=gd,Path=Background}"></datgrid>
```

**property**

```
        ObservableCollection<ProjectTabModel> _BindFiles;
        public ObservableCollection<ProjectTabModel> BindFiles
        {
            get
            {
                return _BindFiles;
            }
            set
            {
                _BindFiles = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(()=>BindFiles);
            }
        }
```

**view model**

```
#region BindProjectFiles
        public void Bindfiletab()
        {

            List<ProjectTabModel> obj = ProjectTabModel.FilesBinding(GlobalProjectID);
            ObservableCollection<ProjectTabModel> obsrvbl = new ObservableCollection<ProjectTabModel>(obj);

            if (obsrvbl.Count > 0)
            {

                BindFiles.Clear();
                foreach (var item in obsrvbl)
                {
                    BindFiles.Add(item);
                }

            }
            else
            {

                NoFileFound = "No File found";
            }
        }



private class DragOverEvent : ProjectTabViewModel, ICommand
        {
            public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
            public void Execute(object sender)
            {
                GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Threading.DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(() =>
         {
//my code stuff here
             }
        });
}
```

Comment: Your code is a mess. You have a view model class that is also an `ICommand`, but is named `...Event`. You are handling a `LblMessageForFiles` UI control in your view model, which goes 100% against MVVM, so you *clearly* have no idea about MVVM. I suggest that you go back to reading and learning about WPF and MVVM, before you continue your project. You are missing far too much knowledge for us to help you here... you need to learn the basics at least before you ask questions here.

Comment: @Sheridan according to my study if we want to do anything with View we make a property of it and bind it in view same is tha case here i ahev property "LblMessageForFiles " that i am using.but the problem that i am facig is that after adding any new entry UI not refreshes.what else you are not undersatnding.

Comment: *what else you are not understanding*... me??? Are you joking? The `System.Windows.Visibility enum` is UI related and does *not* belong in your view model. And why did I assume that `LblMessageForFiles` was a UI element? Because for some bizarre reason, you added a `Lbl` prefix to the name... again, your code is a mess.

Comment: You are not supplying enough information, this is impossible to answer. You don't even show the xaml with the binding. Provide minimal code that reproduces the problem, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. On a sidenote: yes, this code is far below standards.

Comment: Properties exposing ObservableCollections should be read-only.  You should be adding/removing items from the collection.

Comment: And to clarify what Will is saying, you shouldn't have a `set` for BindFiles.

Answer (score 0):

I want to say that your code really needs refactoring. Change your code with below, set breakpoint to BindFiles and trace its state. By the way you shouldn't write code relevant with the UI such as Visibility.Hidden in your ViewModel. Just define a property to change visibility state of control.

```
public void BindFileTab()
 {
        List<ProjectTabModel> obj = ProjectTabModel.FilesBinding(GlobalProjectID);
        BindFiles = new ObservableCollection<ProjectTabModel>(obj);
        LblMessageForFiles = Visibility.Hidden;
        if (BindFiles.Count > 0)
        {
            LblMessageForFiles = Visibility.Hidden;                
        }
        else
        {
            LblMessageForFiles = Visibility.Visible;
            NoFileFound = "No File found";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Since you talk about refactoring, please use `var` instead of spelling out full types, and proper variable names wouldn't hurt either. Apart from that, I'm not sure this code would make a difference or even that it is the way an ObservableCollection is meant to be used. You're simply swapping the backend underneath the property here, so there's no reason to use an Observablecollection in the first place, since the whole point is getting updates on adding/removing.

Comment: @Abdurrahman Köken thanks for answering but this code creates more problem i.e it stops binding the code wit datagrid now.

Comment: vishuminhas: It may not work since you didn't give details about your code. You should give more information. @stijn thank you so much. I'm very grateful to you. I didn't know what the "refactoring" means.